# About declaring and initializing primitive variable in different line outside a method

Tags: java

new to the community, and new to the whole programming world.
While I was studying java, I stumbled on a simple question.

In a main method (or any method), I can declare and initialize a primitive variable on different line just fine. Say,

```
public static void main (Strin[]args){
int age;
age = 42;
}
```

will complile just fine.

But if I tried this outside a method, as a class variable or instance variable,

```
public class test {
int age;
age = 42;
}
```

the code won't compile. It will only work if the variable is declared and initialized in one line. I was wondering why java doesn't allow this outside a method.

Comment: You can't do `age = 42;` outside a method. If you want to declare a constant then do something like `private final int AGE = 42;` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A class body can contain variable declarations and method declarations, but no single statements. When would you expect such a statement to be executed? So your initialization has to be either inline with the declaration (as a shortcut) or in some method, e.g. in the constructor, if you want to initialize the variable when creating a new object.

Answer (score 0):

It is a syntax error! Your code does not comply with the Java syntactic and semantics rules as described in Java Language Specification.

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialise it's value inside the constructor (that's the whole point of a constructor), like

```
public test() {
age = 42;
}
```

For static variables it's possible to give them a value:

```
static int age = 42;
```

Or use a static block:

```
static {
age = 43;
}
```